# Method behaves differently on iPad version of Excel

Tags: excel, office-js

I have the following method that works on all versions of Excel except for Excel iPad. The method returns the filename of the currently open document.

When the document is open from SharePoint, the filename has the full URL to the document. On the iPad the value is just the filename.

#### method:

```
public async getDocumentUrlAsync(): Promise<string | undefined>
{
    return new Promise<string | undefined>((resolve, reject) =>
    {
        Office.context.document.getFilePropertiesAsync(asyncResult =>
        {
            if (asyncResult.status == Office.AsyncResultStatus.Failed)
            {
                reject(asyncResult.error);
            }
            else
            {
                const url = asyncResult.value.url;
                if (Strings.isNullOrEmpty(url))
                {
                    resolve(undefined);
                }
                else
                {
                    resolve(url);
                }
            }
        });
    });
}
```

#### results:

**iPad:** Book1.xslx
**everything else:** https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/dms/documents/Book1.xslx

---

**Is this a bug or by design and how can I get the full url of the document from Excel iPad?**

Comment: Thanks Michael, we can repro this issue, it looks like a bug to me, I created a bug 4256690# to track this issue.

Comment: @RaymondLu Cheers mate, Is there anywhere I can track this bug?

Comment: Sorry, the bug# is for internal tracking, it is not be accessed from external.

Comment: @RaymondLu Is there a way I can be notified of when this bug is fixed, getting worked on, ETA on the fix?

Comment: Could you please share a bit more about your add-in? and usage? we need to set right priority for this work based on the usage.

Comment: @RaymondLu I'd rather discuss that via email. How can I get in contact with you?

Comment: yes, you can contact me via raymonlu@microsoft.com